# Latest Chrome update freeze my application

Tags: google-chrome

I have a huge application I'm working on at work. Last week everything was working fine. I always have the dev console open when I code.

GoogleChorme got an update on Friday (I believe it was Friday) and then I've started noticing that my application just freeze randomly. Now, on Monday, the problem still persist. I've tried everything: going back to another branch/commit, changing some libraries but nothing. Even removing everything and keeping the basic on the app didn't solve the problem.

I just noticed that if I close the dev console the application works like a charm.

Am I missing something or it's just an internal bug by the browser? (even tho is an official release).

The Chrome version is: `73.0.3683.86 official build - 64 bit`.

I've also tried on Canary, Chrome on MacBook and on another Mac and nothing, same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: **I have a huge application** -> Can't reproduce it or create an example since in a small project I'm not facing any issue. I believe is something about the `@Input` and `@Output` event that there are in the Angular app

Comment: We need a stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , is the freezing random or on a request that locks the page? Can you debug the app and see where it freezes up?

Comment: Did you try in another browser, like Firefox?

Comment: If you open Dev tools, go to sources and press pause during a freeze, you should see a stacktrace

Comment: Tbh, I'm not even sure why there are negative votes and people telling him for mcve. I mean, if this issue were to be occurred to me, I can't really tell much except I got stuck on opening Dev Console, what I've tried and where I've tried.

Comment: @NeonNatureEX it's ok, is a common thing to downvote without an explanation. Is sad, but whatever. Since is a problem that can't be reproduced I just guessed that happens because the application has tons of `@Input`

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not much what anyone could advise you as your question is so broad that there are no details where anyone could help.

Nevertheless you can try deleting cookies and browser-cache.
This helps in many general browser-issues when updates are involved.

Taking another browser like MS-Edge, Opera or FireFox could offer you resembling functionality without that bug you described.

Searching or even compiling an old version of Chrome is not advised as browsers get regularly updates where many are security-related. Nevertheless if you're willing to spend time on it it might be useful to search the bug to file a report and for those purposes an old version might be useful to compare.

**Edit**
One more general advise is to open only the required amount of browser-tabs. Browsers are greedy for memory and the browser is able to slow down everything very clear.
On Ajax-Applications like Google-Mail, Facebook, and perhaps even your own, refresh the pages from time to time especially if you make much operations there, this clears some not required internal page-history and frees some memory.
The hardware-related counterpart of this advise is: upgrade memory and perhaps CPU too if possible.